# Libgdx Android, failed to run projects in USB debugging mode

Tags: java, android, eclipse, dalvik, usb-debugging

OK, I have been working on a couple of demo project with libgdx, but I did not have an android device at that time, so I could not test them. I recently bought a tablet and I decided to see if my projects ran on the device connected by USB.

I enabled the USB debugging mode, created a new libgdx project and tested. It works. So the problem is not the connection, but the other projects I am trying to run.

The first project was written while reading the libgdx book. Since by the time I first codded the app I had to reinstall my computer, my android version increased and it was a pain to make it work again with the new version. So it could be the source of the problem. Running as desktop works fine, running as android gives me the following errors:

> [2015-04-19 09:08:37 - CyberGlider-android] Dx warning: Ignoring
>   InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (com.sun.jna.win32.W32APIOptions$2) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced
>   by a compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The
>   recommended solution is to recompile the class from source, using an
>   up-to-date compiler and without specifying any "-target" type options.
>   The consequence of ignoring this warning is that reflective operations
>   on this class will incorrectly indicate that it is *not* an inner
>   class.

It gives me 15 copies of that message because there are 15 classes in the core project.  I tried cleaning all projects but it did not works. Then the errors continue with this:

> [2015-04-19 09:08:37 - CyberGlider-android] Dx  trouble processing
>   "javax/xml/namespace/QName.class":
>
> Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*) when
>   not building a core library.
>
> This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file in
>   your application's project, when using an IDE (such as Eclipse). If
>   you are sure you're not intentionally defining a core class, then this
>   is the most likely explanation of what's going on.
>
> However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
>   namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example, from a
>   non-Android virtual machine project. This will most assuredly not
>   work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the compatibility of your app with
>   future versions of the platform. It is also often of questionable
>   legality.
>
> If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
>   appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine distribution,
>   as opposed to compiling an application -- then use the
>   "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
>
> If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact building an
>   application, then be forewarned that your application will still fail
>   to build or run, at some point. Please be prepared for angry customers
>   who find, for example, that your application ceases to function once
>   they upgrade their operating system. You will be to blame for this
>   problem.
>
> If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a core
>   package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to repackage
>   that code. That is, move the classes in question into your own package
>   namespace. This means that they will never be in conflict with core
>   system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help you in this endeavor.
>   If you find that you cannot do this, then that is an indication that
>   the path you are on will ultimately lead to pain, suffering, grief,
>   and lamentation.
>
> [2015-04-19 09:08:37 - CyberGlider-android] Dx 1 error; aborting
>   [2015-04-19 09:08:37 - CyberGlider-android] Conversion to Dalvik
>   format failed with error 1

---

Then I also have a second app which was started on my new installed computer. So I did not have to change the android version in the process. When I tried to run the app on the android device it gives me the following errors as pop up windows:

> Unhandled event loop exception GC overhead limit exceeded
>
> Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded GC overhead limit
>   exceeded

The console log gives me this

> [2015-04-19 09:14:38 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: GC overhead
>   limit exceeded [2015-04-19 09:14:38 - PixelBoard_Launcher-android]
>   Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: GC overhead
>   limit exceeded

And eclipse gives me an out of memory error and ask to close itself.

The launching process also takes a few minutes.

---

I was first wondering if there were some limitations to run an app in USB debugging mode. Is it possible that the apps above does not run in USB mode, but if I build and register the APK it would work.

Else the only solution would be to recode everything from scratch. Add one class at a time and see what makes the program fail.

Does anybody has an idea where I should start investigating?

Comment: have you tried cleaning the project?

Comment: are you sure that you imported correct classes to your project? From your error it appears that import com.sun.. classes but it might not be what you need. Try cleaning imports and then import com.badlogic... instead of com.sun.. classes.

Comment: Yes I cleaned the project. Right now I am thinking to rebuild a new project and copy the source files into the new project. So that Anything I could have screwed up in the project modification will be gone.

Comment: As for the "GC overhead limit exceeded" of the second app. Maybe there is a memory allocation bug in my app. I'll try to isolate the parts of my code and see if I can manage to find the buggy section.

Comment: OK, I managed to rebuild the project of the first app and it works. The screen layout is horrible and touch screen does not match, but at least it draws what it is supposed to.

Comment: For my second app, I tried disabling most features. I did not load the database. I did not start a second thread, and the only thing I am drawing on the screen is a black screen with the FPS counter. And still it does not work.  I am thinking to make a parallel test project on copy each file of code gradually. I don't think it has any thing to do with what the program do because it fails before even starting.